# You do not have the following permissions on CodeUnit Prova: Execute

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

In Dynamics Nav 2018 I made this codeunit **50006** called **Prova**:

```
OnRun()
MESSAGE('Hello');
```

When I Ctrl+R or run it will display this error message:

```
You do not have the following permissions on CodeUnit Prova: Execute
```

My user has **SUPER** permissions.

If it's a license thing I really don't know how to check that.

How can I run this codeunit? Or check if it's a license issue?

**EDIT:**

I've tested to create a REPORT and run it:

```
OnPreReport()
  PurchHeader.GET('CF-181003');    
  PurchHeader."Buy-from Vendor No." := 'RONALDO';
  PurchHeader.MODIFY;
```

It ran but I got this error:

```
You do not have the following permissions on TableData Purch. Inv. Header: Modify
```

Comment: Have you tried running your codeunit from a CRONUS database, which you can install on a demo machine with the developer tools? If it runs there then most likely it will be the license installed on the NAV instance. They allocate object ranges, e.g 50000..50010, so check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it IS a license restriction. There are two options to check that.

1. There's a txt file that you can get along with license flf file. In this txt file you can find all allowed ranges in readable format.
2. Create a page for table called License Permissions. There you will see all objects available to you. See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I don't see table License Permissions, I see: Tenant License State and License Agreement

Comment: That's why I said to create a page. It is a system/hidden table. Just start creating a page and  type `Livense Permission` to `Table` field. Create a List page.

Comment: Keep in mind that RTС works under license that is uploaded to server or database. It is not the same license you are using in Dev Environment (fat old client).