# How can I find all my available objects in my NAV license?

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2018

I'm trying to create objects with this customer license:

[image]

I should have space for new objects as license says... but how I can find which object ids are available for each object type?

This is what I get when trying to create a table:

[image]

[image]

If I try with this developer license I get the same error:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Checking with License Viewer as @ian_scho suggested throws this error when trying to open any of my licenses:

[image]

Comment: We create  customized objects in the 50000+ range. As you already stated, you also need the license to be adapted for that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t have a permission txt file as mentioned in the other answer (one who gave you the license undoubtedly has the file or at least can download it again if lost), then the answer is the same as before

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72907256/1820340

Keep in mind that

1. you need to restart nav server after you imported license.
2. They're different places you can store license at. You can stride in at database or at SQL server. The one in database overrides the one on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a license viewer?
https://forum.mibuso.com/discussion/1897/navision-license-viewer-v0-1-2-17

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Edited the question with this testing result

Comment: Another example. Let us know if it works for you. https://moxie4nav.wordpress.com/2016/08/18/check-license-state-of-objects/

Answer (score 0):

This is the most obvious answer but can you see a file called "Permission Report Detailed.txt" in the same zip file or directory as the "nnnnn.flf" license file?
Ask for it, if you don't have it.

Comment: Where should I ask for it? There is no such txt file

Comment: If I had installed the license on a client's system I would have both left it on the server the NAV instance had been installed on and sent it to the person in charge of IT infrastructure.

Comment: Yes correct, I did that and I have the correct license but I also want to know how to do things myself if it's possible